# bootstrap-table urlencode() in data-url doesn't work

Tags: php, html, urlencode, bootstrap-table, data-uri

I'm facing at an issue when i try to encode the url in data-url
e.g :

```
<table id="table" data-url="<?php echo urlencode($dataurl) ?>" data-escape="true"....>
```

I tried to add this :

```
data-content-type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Are there any restrictions?.

Comment: Where this $dataurl comes from ? What is the problem ? For effective help, you need to tell what you expect and what you get, provide us with the relevant source...

Comment: You're not supposed to encode the full URL.

Comment: this variable is inside a php page with $dataurl="my_url?a=1&b=2..Etc" 
that works if the url in not encoded, but it doesn't work if i use urlencode($dataurl)

Comment: I agree more background information needs to be given. there is a parameters option for passing any additional variables automatically that can be implemented.

please give more information on what problem you are solve.

Answer (score 0):

`urlencode` is a function to encode the query variables of a url, such that tokens like ? and & get properly encoded without breaking the query.

> urlencode ( string $str ) : string This function is convenient when
>   encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient
>   way to pass variables to the next page.

Example:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="mycgi?foo=', urlencode($userinput), '">';
?>
```

See more at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

---

In your specific case, depending of what `$dataurl` is, you get seomthing like this:

```
<?php $dataurl = "http://someurl.com?var1=".urlencode($var1); ?>
<table id="table" data-url="<?php echo $dataurl; ?>" data-escape="true"....>
```